# How would you model this cloth seam/border?

Tags: modeling, geometry, shrinkwrap, curve-modifier, seams

I am trying to model this outer seam boundary. I tried half pipe and shrinkage modifier, also curves, but it all looks crappy.... I don't know how to connect it to the main model. I appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. This is not a direct answer to your question, but are you certain that modelling the seams is the right approach? For small details like this, using the material is often a much better idea. If you model the seams you are committing a very large number of vertices to an area of your object that is barely visible. Those extra vertices will slow down your render times (quite considerably). If you 'paint' the seams on to your object as part of the material, there will be almost no impact to your render times whatsoever

Comment: If you would like a demo on how to add seams using the material instead of modelling them, please open a new question. I need to step away from my PC for a few hours but if it is not answered this evening I will take a look at it.

Comment: I've just realised that I may have misunderstood what you mean by 'seams'. If you mean the white stitching, my comments above still apply. If you are referring to the thicker (blue) piece of leather around the edges of the bag, simple loop cuts and extrusions of some of the faces on the main object should to the trick.

Comment: yea the stitching i already painted. i gonna try to extrude the edges, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to BSE,

I think what you want here is the **Extrude Faces Along Normals** option.
I do not have your model, but I will try to demonstrate using a cube:

[image]

Adding some loop-cuts where I want the seams to be (you likely will not have to do this step):

[image]

Selecting the faces I would like to extrude (along normals):

[image]

To extrude faces along normals, press **Alt+E > Extrude Faces Along Normals**.

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Obviously this doesn't look anything like a bag because of the lack of faces, but hopefully it gets the point across.

Comment: Thank you so much! "Alt+E > Extrude Faces Along Normals" was what i was looking for!

Comment: Don't mention it :) If you wouldn't mind, could you accept my answer using the tick mark to the left? This will help other users with a similar issue to find this solution. An upvote would also be much appreciated.