# Extrude outward proportionally

Tags: extrude

I'd like to extrude the selected part of this object outward however the way I am trying to achieve this doesn't work. I mean the object doesn't extrude properly in every direction.

Here is my approach. I press the  <kbd>E</kbd> button, then  <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then  <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> at the end. And the effect is as in the video.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G40ke.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1):

Please try using <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> *Extrude Faces Along Normals*

Please see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276100/how-would-you-model-this-cloth-seam-border/276151#276151) for more details on this function.